# How to create element with arbitrary shape using xbim toolkit?

Tags: c#, bim, xbim

I just started using xbim library, but there are lack of manual.
I've already checked some example like [this](https://docs.xbim.net/examples/proper-wall-in-3d.html).
But there aren't enough to create elements I wanted.
I would like to solve following problem as first step.

- Creating walls for simple floor plan
  Here, I would like to know how to create and set the position of the wall using global coordinates and object coordinate system.
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehzjr.png)
- Create a simple shaped door.
  I would like to know how to create a model with arbitrary shape here.
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfNbs.png)
  I hope you can help me.
  Thanks in advance!
  Serafina.M

checked a little [example](https://docs.xbim.net/examples/examples-list.html), [manuals](https://docs.xbim.net/XbimDocs/)